# What happened to Mono 2.10.6

Tags: f#, mono, monodevelop

Anyone know where I can download an installer for OSX of Mono 2.10.6, it doesn't seem to have made it to the website but my MonoDevelop is looking for it.

Comment: Just curious--why did you tag this question with F#?

Comment: Because I am trying to get the excellent Pit (http://pitfw.org/), an F# to Javascript compiler, working in MonoDevelop and I knew there were some good F# people out there who might help.

Answer (score 1):

With some link digging I found [**these**](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/2.10.6/macos-10-x86/1/):

- http://download.mono-project.com/archive/2.10.6/macos-10-x86/1/MonoFramework-MDK-2.10.6_1.macos10.xamarin.x86.dmg
- http://download.mono-project.com/archive/2.10.6/macos-10-x86/1/MonoFramework-MRE-2.10.6_1.macos10.xamarin.x86.dmg